# How to get default LandscapeLeft Orientation in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation

Sorry if this question is duplicate, but I can't find the same solution.
In iOS6, if I want to set default orientation for one UIViewController, I just use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

But how to do same in iOS5, I test both:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);//not default
}
and
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft);// = return NO;
}
```

But the default orientation always Portrait.Any suggestion?

Comment: Just problem of iPhone 5.0 simulator! Thanks all for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call the below method where you want to check the status of orientation.happy coding :-)

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self CheckForViewForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void) CheckForViewForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        //Ur lable portrait view
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        //Ur lable for landscape view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this for whole application, change supported orientation UISupportedInterfaceOrientations in app.plist file

Comment: Just only one ViewController sir.Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes in some specific scenarios i`ve rotated view manually:
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.0);
If you cant find any proper solution, this is your last hope.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if (orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
 // do some 

}

return YES;
}
```

Include both the methods to support both 5 and 6

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

for that single View controller.

Comment: Thanks!Just work until I rotate to landscape, default always portrait.