# iOS app initial screen orientation does not work for landscape orientation

Tags: ios, orientation, landscape-portrait

I'm working on this iPhone app, whose orientation works all fine except first screen. The first screen also works fine if the device is in portrait orientation, but not for landscape orientation.

Interestingly, if I rotate device at the first screen, it also adjust well.

The problem looks to me is that the app always assumes the device is in portrait orientation, so the first screen is always shown in `portrait orientatio`n even if the device is in landscape orientation.

I tried to add `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` at the end of executing first screen, but didn't work. `The willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method which calls the rotating function (the one that works well for other screens after first screen) seems to think there's no need to adjust subviews.
Since the rotating function works very well for later screens, I guess I probably missed something (maybe outside of the code). Wonder if someone can point it out for me.Between , I specified "initial launch orientation" in plist to landscape, it didn't work either.

Thanks, Please help Me

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516992/how-to-get-default-landscapeleft-orientation-in-ios5

Comment: check my SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933089/i-want-to-make-my-appliaction-only-in-landscape-orientation-in-ios-both-ios-5-a

Answer (score 1):

For iPhone & iPod, launch image(Default) does not support landscape orientation.

Read "App Launch (Default) Images" section from [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)